# Php get variable params at each modification not from script

Tags: php, load, emulation

How does it possible to get variable modificated values, after script ended? im going to make a small and very simple caching system, for start to cache just needs to put "cache" commented where need to start cache and same when ends, only problem is to emulate all script and, as i said, get each changed instance of var.

Comment: I think it's not possible to emulate them because the scope has been ended after the whole run. You can create a variable in higher level scope and populate the results in it, next you can use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is more simpler, just integrate the caching in your script, the process would be

1. verify there is some cache and it's not expired
2. if there is some not expired cache use it, end
3. render the page and capture it using ob_* functions
4. build the cache

This way you don't have to emulate anything, just to wait that some people visit the page, plus you don't built cache for page that are never visited.

Comment: My idea is to copy code file and change vars values to srings, without their calculates

Comment: In this way, you should care about the caches like paging. I mean when a page is going to have several page navigation you should be aware of every page to cache it with a different name.

Comment: @MahanGM: yes you should handle the paging and have unique name for each page

Comment: Simple compress old file and control files changing, if file was edit rhen refresh it, id not needs, just same name with addition some chars to end of name

Comment: @MahanGM: after you can create the cache identifier using the page URI and the parameters $_POST & $_GET

Comment: As i told i dont want to get last value of variables, i need each instance

Comment: I think i have invented how to do it, but it not the best way..